# Creating A Strut To The Center Of The Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, landscape

I have three views that are in a horizontal line. The middle view is centered horizontally while the other two are the same distance away, one to the left and one to the right.

When I rotate the screen to landscape, I want the middle view to stay centered horizontally, and I want the other two views to stay the same distance away from the center.

Is there an easy way to do this in Xcode?

Comment: are you using interface builder or are you creating your interface with code?

Comment: A little of both. I have a placeholder to make setting the frame and autoresizing mask easier, but I am adding an imageview from code. I am using interface builder for the struts right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is harder to do with springs & struts and setting the frame, and is simpler to handle with Auto Layout constraints, if you can use those in your app. See [this video from Justin Williams](http://vimeopro.com/360conferences/360idev-2013/video/75232527) for a good overview of why.

If you need to stick with springs & struts and setting the frame in code, for some reason, you'll have to recompute the center of the super view, and then use that to set the .center of your subview.